# Kitchen Faucet Low Flow by design?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

Just moved in and noticed the kitchen faucet has low flow. About 1 GPM.
Rest of the house is fine.

Seems like the faucet supply lines are too narrow.

Never seen this before.
Is this normal?

The extreme left and right lines are the hot and cold.
The other two are the pull down head in and out lines.

The connectors are 1/2 inch for reference.

[image]

Here's a pic of the full flow:

[image]

Comment: Check whether the aerator is rated for 1.5 gpm (green) or 2.5 (red). https://www.homedepot.com/p/NEOPERL-1-5-GPM-Dual-Thread-Water-Saving-Faucet-Aerator-37-0086-98/100666002. They even go as low as 1.2 gpm and .5

Comment: Also, remove the aerator and see f the flow improves. Make sure the supply valves are fully open.

Comment: Aerator is 2.2 GPM. Flow is the same without aerator and valves fully open.

Comment: Assuming that's 3/8 copper then the flow rate should be 1-2 gpm according to http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_category_files/11448-Flow-Rate-Chart.pdf but that's dependent on the water pressure coming into your home. None of the other fixtures use such small tubing? My kitchen sink uses the same stuff and my 2.5 gpm aerator supplies adequate water. A kitchen generally uses the most water so it would make sense that they would forcefully restrict water flow here; whether that's an overall good idea is debatable.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the water flow at full blast?

Comment: Made some updates and added the flow pic. None of the other fixtures have this small tubing.

Comment: How do things look in your basement? Can you check for partially closed water valves? If contaminants such as dirt or rust ever entered your lines from the city then there's the possibility of a clog in those small lines. Really the only thing left to try is to disconnect the braided line from the brass coupling and see whether the water seems restricted coming from the braided cable (you'll need a bucket and a second person for this). Shut off the water valve which supplies the kitchen before doing this.

Comment: ^^ If you're not comfortable doing this then it's simply time to call a plumber.

Comment: FWIW, I recently had loose rust degrade my shower valve down to a trickle.

Comment: Thanks -- looks normal in the basement. Do you think those thin tubes from the faucet is the thing restricting the flow?

Comment: Sounds like a 49% possibility; the other 49% is the faucet itself, I reserve 2% for the truly unexpected. Do you plan to try something yourself or call a plumber? I'd be interested in hearing about what ultimately fixes your issue.

Comment: I'll test the flow of the braided line myself (by shutting off the value, remove the braided line to faucet line connection and then turning it back on with a bucket).
I'll post back results later tonight.

Comment: Aerator slows the flow of my kitchen faucet by 35%. I may take it apart and remove a few of the screens. Not so drastic, but you should unscrew the aerator at least yearly, and look for trapped mineral deposits. They can slow you to a trickle, but rinse off easily.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Please read the third comment.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Saw it. Just pointing out that for some people, the aerator *is* the problem.

Comment: @user113080 Any luck with this?

Comment: Looks like it's the faucet intake tubes or some other mechanism inside the faucet. The braided line from the piping comes out fast. I will be replacing the faucet with a new one (rated 2+ GPM)

Comment: Good luck to you! Isn't home ownership fun! Fyi, once you fix it then you can post your own answer and accept it. I'll gladly come back to upvote it :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks for all the help MonkeyZeus. Might take a while to replace as I have 10 other issues that needs addressing.